# Fatal error: Access level to .... ::read_children() must be public (as in class ....)

Tags: woocommerce, fatal-error

i have a problem
after update woocommerce this problem occurred

I appreciate your help

**Fatal error:** Access level to AtWCTourDataStoreCPT::read_children() must be public (as in class WC_Product_Variable_Data_Store_CPT) in /home3/abrobadg/public_html/wp-content/themes/adventure-tours/includes/classes/AtWCTourDataStoreCPT.php on line 58

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3lbH.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpDBx.jpg)

Comment: This error is related to your theme… You should report it on [Adventure Tours theme authors support pages](https://themeforest.net/item/adventure-tours-wordpress-tourtravel-theme/12781942/support). StackOverFlow don't handle any support software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. first make a **backup/copy** of this file : `\wp-content\themes\adventure-tours\includes\classes\AtWCTourDataStoreCPT.php`
2. change this two functions’ visibility from protected to **public** at *line 25 and 29* like this:

`protected function read_children (...” to “public function read_children (....`

**and**

`protected function read_variation_attributes( ....” to “public function read_variation_attributes( ....`

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Change read_children for read_parent and read_variation_attributes for read_parent_attributes like in the code below:

protected function read_parent( &$product, $force_read = false ) {
  return $this->is_variable( $product ) ? parent::parent( $product, $force_read ) : array();
}

protected function read_parent_attributes( &$product ) {
  return $this->is_variable( $product ) ? parent::read_variation_attributes( $product ) : array();
}